# Tween.js - Is it possible to tween a variable?

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween.js, tweenjs

So I have been playing with three.js and tween.js and I am wondering if it is possible to tween a variable?

What I've tried:

1)

```
tween = new TWEEN.Tween(renderergl.toneMappingExposure).to( "0.001", 1000 ).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut).onComplete(function() {
// Finished
}).start();
```

2. 

```
tween = new TWEEN.Tween(renderergl.toneMappingExposure).to( 0.001, 1000 ).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut).onComplete(function() {
// Finished
}).start();
```

3. 

```
var toneMap = renderergl.toneMappingExposure;
tween = new TWEEN.Tween(toneMap).to( "0.001", 1000 ).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut).onComplete(function() { }).start();
```

Both give this result: `Object prototype may only be an Object or null: 0.001`

I am not even sure if vars can be animated can someone confirm?

Comment: Seems it needs to be like this: `tween = new TWEEN.Tween(renderergl).to( {toneMappingExposure:0.001}, 1000 ).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut).start()`

Comment: @prisoner849 Thanks! if you put this as an answer I can mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.to()` you need to pass duration and an object with properties and their values you want to change in the object of `.Tween()`.
So your code will be like this:

```js
tween = new TWEEN.Tween(renderergl)
.to( {toneMappingExposure:0.001}, 1000 )
.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut)
.start()
```